# MCImageManager installation for .NET

Tags: .net, failed-installation, mcimagemanager

Just bought MCImageManager for .NET yesterday.  Followed the installation instructions to the letter. Now my .NET 4.0 VB VS2010 web project won't build. Full details at http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=22436.  What I need is "proper" installation instructions. It doesn't seem right that you have multiple copies of dll's in the javascript AND the root bin directories.

If someone could tell me where to put the various bits of the download in my project I'd be grateful.  Moxiecode support are on holiday according to an admin message on their support forum so need to get this going.

Regards,

Craig